# How to use Mockito to populate POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I have a POJO class:

```
@Data @Document
public class RoomPreferences{
    private TypeEnum         roomType;
    private BigDecimal       minLen;
    private BigDecimal       maxLen;
    private List<BigDecimal> defaultPrices;
}
```

I want to populate a RoomPreferences object at test and I am using Mockito, but my RoomPreferences object's fields are always `null`.

```
public class TestingClass {
   @Mock private RoomPreferences roomPreferences;
   @InjectMocks public RoomServiceImpl roomService;

   @Before
   public void init() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
       when(roomPreferences.getMinLen()).thenReturn(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes because you are mocking RoomPreference Object but not said create mock values for object fields. Maybe you can create your own mock object builder class for RoomPreferences. Or you can set every object field in @BeforeClass method for one time for every test classes.

Comment: Thank you. But when I do: when(roomPreferences.getMinLen()).thenReturn(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));, i assign a Mock value to the field of the RoomPreference mock. What would be the correct way to assign a value to the minLen::BigDecimal field?

Comment: Don't mock value objects, because they don't have _behavior_; just create one and set its values the way you want it.

Comment: Try to refine your question. Give us more context; what do you want to test and why? How is this question related to Spring/Spring-Boot specifically? (Possibly update your tags). Further (in your comment) ``What would be the correct way to assign a value to the minLen::BigDecimal field?`` is too broad. Answering your question in its current state is difficult (= guess-work on our side) and will not result in clear (= good) answer; and thus, it won't be so helpful for other community members down the road. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe field setter can help to you. https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldSetter/set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I read out of this testing class:

```
public class TestingClass {
   @Mock private RoomPreferences roomPreferences;
   @InjectMocks public RoomServiceImpl roomService;

   @Before
   public void init() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
       when(roomPreferences.getMinLen()).thenReturn(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
       ...
   }
}
```

is that `roomService` of type `RoomServiceImpl` has an attribute of type `RoomPreferences`. And this attribute will be injected with the mocked object "`roomPreferences`".

The mocked object won't be populated with any value of the real class.

What you do is define what the mock should do when a method (as in the real class) is called on it:

```
when(roomPreferences.getMinLen()).thenReturn(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
```

If you wan to assing a value to a property then don't mock the class and use the real class instead.

I am guessing that the problem you are facing is setting the RoomPreferences attribute in the roomService object. If that is the case you should add that class to the question.